# Python convert string of characters into proper list structure

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a string variable,

```
str = "b'[["innovation",3],["marketing",3],["credentials",2],["trends",2]]'
```

What's the best way to convert them into easy-to-process python structures like `json/dict/list/tuple`?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use `str` as a variable name, since it will mask the builtin Python data type name.

Comment: where does this string come from? Is it JSON or Python? If it's Python you shouldn't generate such strings in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> my_str = b'[["innovation",3],["marketing",3],["credentials",2],["trends",2]]'
>>> 
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(my_str)
[['innovation', 3], ['marketing', 3], ['credentials', 2], ['trends', 2]]
>>>
```

Or `json.loads()`:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(my_str)
[[u'innovation', 3], [u'marketing', 3], [u'credentials', 2], [u'trends', 2]]
>>>
```

Note: Don't use python key-words and module names as your variable names.

Comment: there's a b at the beginning of the string

Comment: that's fine, I managed to do something like json.loads(my_str[2:])